# How to pass column name of a file as variable in awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I trying to printing the data in the particular columns by passing them int awk command

I have tried using `"-v"` to set is as variable but its considering `"$"` as string. And my delimiter is special character `^A` (ctrl+v+a).

```
vi test_file.dat
a^Ab^Ac^Ad^Ae^Af^Ag^Ah^Ai^Aj^Ak^Al^Am^An^Ao^Ap
```

Working code

```
awk -F'^A' '{print $2,$5,$7}' test_file.dat
```

It's Printing

```
b e g
```

But if I try

```
export fields='$2,$5,$7'
export file='test_file.dat'
awk -v sample_file="$test_file.dat" -v columns="$fileds" -F'^A'  '{print columns}' sample_file
```

It's printing

```
$2 $5 $7
```

I expect the output as

```
b e g
```

And I want to pass the delimiter, columns, file name as a parameter like

```
export fields='$2,$5,$7'
export file='test_file.dat'
export delimiter='^A'
awk -v sample_file="$test_file.dat" -v columns="$fields" -v file_delimiter="$delimiter" -F'file_delimiter'  '{print columns}' sample_file
```

Comment: Got it , i haven't tried passing the file as parameter . But my main concern is how to pass the delimiter.

Comment: actually, you could just expand `$fields` in the shell, eg. `awk -F"$delimiter" '{print '"$fields"'}' "$sample_file"`

Answer (score 1):

In awk, the `$` symbol is effectively an operator which takes the field numbers as arguments. The field names are expressions, which is why `$NF` works for denoting the last field: `NF` is *evaluated* by the `$` operator. So as you can see, we should not include the dollar sign in the field names.

If you're using the environment to pass material to Awk, the right thing to do is to have Awk pick it up from the environment.

The environment can be accessed using the `ENVIRON` associative array. If a variable called `delimiter` holds the field separator, we might do something like

```
BEGIN { FS = ENVIRON["delimiter"] }
```

in the Awk code. Then we aren't dealing with yet another round of shell parameter interpolation issues.

We can pick up the field numbers similarly. The `split` function can be used to get them into an array. Refer to this one-liner:

```
$ fields=1,3,9 awk 'BEGIN { split(ENVIRON["fields"], f, ",") ;
                            for (i in f)
                              printf("f[%d] = %d\n", i, f[i]) ; }'
f[1] = 1
f[2] = 3
f[3] = 9
```

GNU Awk, the expression `length(f)` gives the number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `awk` to see the special characters while reading the file you could use `cat -v file` (there might be a built-in method, although I'm not aware of it). Then the key to getting the character `^A` (<kbd>Control-A</kbd>) delimiter to be recognized is to escape it with a `\`, otherwise the regex capability of `awk`,`gawk`, etc. is to treat `^` as start of line.

```
export fields='$2,$5,$7'
export test_file='test_file.dat'
export delimiter='\\^A'

awk -F $delimiter '{ print '$fields' }' < <(cat -v test_file)
```

There's also no need to set `awk` variables for `bash` variables that have already set — so you can eliminate all of them essentially.

One thing to note if you did want to set them in `awk` is that `columns` wouldn't work because usually setting an `awk` variable from a `bash` variable would be assigned individually. For example `-v var1='$2' -v var2='$5' -v var3='$7'`, so you'd end up for `{ print var1, var2, var3 }` in `awk`. It's doubtful a single string can translated it into three variables without additional steps.

Comment: @shelter: Yes, thanks for catching that, `FS=` is what I meant. Regarding the `^A`, I think it really depends on how it is within the original file; if it's visible as `^A` went `cat` for example, then it should work from my example, which is how the OP is showing it... but still unclear as you mentioned. Cheers!

Comment: Agree about `cat` being the final arbiter, but O.P. does say the `^A` char is created with "`(ctrl+v+a)`", which is `vi` speak for create a Crtl-A char (I think !) ;-) . Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks all , I know it's not that easy for passing `^A` but is there a way in awk to choose delimiter based on argument like `if $a=1 then -F'^A' or -F'|'`.